# Can't mount VMware tools cdrom in VMware Player

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, mount, kali-linux, vmware-player

I know this should be easy, but I'm having a hell of a time figuring out where the vmware tools cdrom is (for instance it's not `/dev/cdrom`) and so I can't figure out how to mount it. I'm on Kali Linux, using VMware player 7. The VM I'm doing this on is Metasploitable 2(ubuntu)

I go to *Virtual Machine > Install VMware Tools...* a little window comes up saying I should press install, then mount the cdrom in the guest vm, decompress the installer and run vmware-install.pl. However, having googled around for some time, I can't figure out where the cdrom is. Most tutorials say to do something akin to this:

```
mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
```

Fine. Except there is no `/dev/cdrom` or indeed anything remotely similar inside `/dev`. So I get the error:

```
mount: special device /dev/cdrom does not exist
```

There is a `~/cdrom` and a `/media/cdrom` and a `/media/cdrom0` but all of these result in the error:

```
mount: /media/cdrom0 is not a block device
```

Which I think is due to me attempting to mount something that's not in `/dev`. Also, creating `/dev/cdrom` and attempting to mount results in the above error also.

I have checked and made sure that the vmware tools iso is in the virtual cd drive(it's connected to `/usr/lib/vmware/isoimages/linux.iso` on the host machine. This is done automatically by selecting *Virtual Machine > Install VMware Tools...* ). I am at a loss as to how to continue, and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you don't see it mounted when you run the command `mount` right?

Comment: @FrankThomas No, it's not there

Comment: Make sure the virtual cd of the guest is connected (if "connect at start" is not checked, it will not be connected automatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to mount `/dev/sr0` instead of `/dev/cdrom`. So the following command worked:

```
sudo mount /dev/sr0 /mnt/cdrom
```

I had to create `/mnt/cdrom` with `mkdir` for this to work.

Comment: This also worked for me.  Can you explain why this was the solution?  Still trying to learn my way around Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but with vmware workstation 12 and ubuntu server. It WASN'T solved by typing `sudo mount /dev/sr0 /mnt/cdrom` because for whatever reason the iso was on a different drive.

**The solution**-
after clicking on install/upgrade VMware Tools type

`blkid -c /dev/null`

The above command shows all mounted and unmounted drives. I saw
 `/dev/sr1: LABEL=”VMware Tools” TYPE=”iso9660”`

I used the above information to determine which drive to mount. Next type

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/cdrom
sudo mount /dev/sr1 /mnt/cdrom
ls /mnt/cdrom
```

You should see information similar to the picture below
[image: vmware-tools version]

Use that information to determine which version you need, then (adjusting the version as appropriate) type

```
tar xzvf /mnt/cdrom/VMwareTools-10.0.6-3595377.tar.gz -C /tmp/
cd /tmp/vmware-tools-distrib/
sudo ./vmware-install.pl –d
```

and you are done. I hope this helps someone.

[image: vmware after installation information]

RESEARCH

[blkid information](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/show-all-unmounted-disk-labels-722515/)

[How to install vmware-tools from command line using ubuntu server](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1022525)